# how to download image using html agility pack

Tags: c#, parsing, xpath, html-agility-pack

i have seen further question answers but cannot get a clear answer.

```
foreach (HtmlNode cat2 in doci.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//a/@href | //img/@src"))
```

in this i am getting src in img tag i want to download that image and store it into database.what should i do? is it possible with html agility pack to download image if so, then tell me how to get and assign it to a variable then i can store in my DB

```
var imagePath = cat2.Attributes["src"].Value;
```

this is not working too

Comment: I have no idea why my answer is being down-voted.I have shown in my answer exactly how to retrieve the image and assign it to a variable (which is what the OP asked for!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code you have write will only get the link of the image and u can save it in your DB and then make a client use that stored URL of the image and then u can download the image thanks

Comment: ohh thanks thanks dude for all your support people don't even reply and i am blocked from asking questions thank u again